# Why aren't backtics giving me curly quotes?

Tags: xetex, luatex, punctuation, tufte, ligatures

I'm using the appropriate keystrokes to get curly quotes, but I'm not getting them. What is wrong here?

```
\documentclass[nols,nohyper,openany, letterpaper]{tufte-book}



\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214, 88, 18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setsansfont{Georgia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=Ahrenge}




\begin{document}

%\maketitle

%\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Notes}



\bigskip

\section{Please help}

Here is a ``quote,'' but it is ``quite fake.''

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to tell XeLaTeX that you wish to use standard TeX ligatures:

```
\documentclass[nols,nohyper,openany, letterpaper]{tufte-book}



\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214, 88, 18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Georgia}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Georgia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=Ahrenge}




\begin{document}

%\maketitle

%\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Notes}



\bigskip

\section{Please help}

Here is a ``quote,'' but it is ``quite fake.''

\end{document}
```

[image: XeLaTeX]

If you are using LuaTeX rather than XeTeX:

```
\documentclass[nols,nohyper,openany, letterpaper]{tufte-book}



\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214, 88, 18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Georgia}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Georgia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=Ahrenge}




\begin{document}

%\maketitle

%\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Notes}



\bigskip

\section{Please help}

Here is a ``quote,'' but it is ``quite fake.''

\end{document}
```

[image: LuaLaTeX]

As the manual explains, this second syntax will also work for XeLaTeX because `fontspec` will translate it into the `Mapping=tex-text` invocation. See `fontspec`'s documentation for further details and other options.

Comment: In fact, the documentation prefers `Ligatures=TeX` in *both* engines.

Comment: The bit I looked up said that `Ligatures=TeX` would be turned into `Mapping=...` in the case of XeLaTeX but that `Mapping=...` was really the mechanism involved. If anything, it implied that the mapping one to the other was there just so things more-or-less worked as expected when people used the 'wrong' configuration setting. [Note: I'm not saying this is correct - just that's what the `fontspec` manual indicated.]

Comment: You are right, but there's nothing wrong with only using `Ligatures`, that's all. A quote from the manual: “Using the `tex-text` mapping is also equivalent to writing `Ligatures=TeX`. The use of the latter syntax is recommended for better compatibility with LuaTEX documents.”

Comment: @Manuel Fair enough.